# How to fix this JQuery script that show a table row only if a specific value of a select input tag is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am absolutly new in **JQuery** development and I have to do the following thing.

Into a form I have something like this:

```
<tr>
    ..........................
    ..........................

    <td>
        <s:select list="kmProjectInfoStatusList" id="selectStatus" headerKey="0"
                  listValue="status"
                  listKey="idProjectInfoStatus"
                  headerValue="-- Please Select --"
                  name="kmProjectInfo.status.idProjectInfoStatus"
                />
    </td>

</tr>
    ..........................
    ..........................

<tr id="datePickerRow" style="display:none">

    <td>
        <sj:datepicker name="kmProjectInfo.startingDate" id="since" maxlength="10"
                       displayFormat="dd/mm/yy" showOn="button" duration="slow"
                       showAnim="slideDown" readonly="true" changeMonth="true"
                       changeYear="true"
                />
    </td>
</tr>
```

As you can see the form contains a table that contains itself a row having **id="datePickerRow"** and that for default it is not shown (infact it have the **display:none** CSS settings).

Upper this hidden row there is a td element that contains:

```
<s:select list="kmProjectInfoStatusList" id="selectStatus" headerKey="0"
          listValue="status"
          listKey="idProjectInfoStatus"
          headerValue="-- Please Select --"
          name="kmProjectInfo.status.idProjectInfoStatus"
/>
```

This is only a **Struts 2 tag** that wrap this standard HTML **input tag** of type **select**, infact in the generated html code I have:

```
<select id="selectStatus" name="kmProjectInfo.status.idProjectInfoStatus">
    <option value="0">-- Please Select --</option>
    <option value="1">Closed</option>
    <option value="2">Active</option>
    <option value="3">Testing</option>
    <option value="4">Starting</option>
</select>
```

So what I need to do is create a **JQuery** script that if the selected value is:

```
<option value="4">Starting</option>
```

then show the hidden row having **id="datePickerRow"**.

I am thinking that maybe I can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#selectStatus").bind("SELECT AN OPTION VALUE", function (event, data) {

        if (data.rslt.obj.attr("value") == 4) {
            $('#datePickerRow').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#datePickerRow').hide();
        }

    })
});
```

Can be a good idea or is it wrong and I can do this thing in some other way?

If my idea is ok I can't achieve it because I know that the **.bind()** method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements (and in my case the event handler is the function that show or hide the row having **id=datePickerRow**) but I can't understand what is the propper event to put inside bind(**"SELECT AN OPTION VALUE"**

What is the right binded event for the selection of a value into a **select input tag** ?

My second doubt is related about how to correctly extract the selected value of this **select input tag**.

I have wrote:

```
data.rslt.obj.attr("value")
```

but maybe it is wrong because I think that this is not an attribute.

How ca I fix my script to correctly work?

Tnx

Comment: You can bind to `change` event.

Comment: @jcubic I am very newby in JQuery. Please can you provide me a code snippet about how to fix my script?

Comment: `$("#selectStatus").bind("change", function() {`

Comment: @jcubic TNX, and about the data.rslt.obj.attr("value") to retrieve the value is it correct or is it wrong?

Comment: You should use `$(this).val();`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wfjp2stj/